# Цикл в запросе sqlite

Tags: sqlite

Нужно обновить все записи в таблице с шагом 5.

Comment: Нужно обновить каждую 5 строку.

Comment: а в чём именно вопрос, что значит каждую 5, учесть что порядка как такового нет. Как это предполагается делать (SQL - запрос, хранимая процедура, расширение языка, курсоры). В общем постарайтесь задавать вопросы развёрнуто.

Comment: Есть 1000 записей, мне нужно sql запросом обновить определенную ячейку, с id, которое в цикле увеличивается на 5.

Comment: `Update table set [bla-bla-bla] where (id % 5 = 0)` так что ли?

Comment: Желательно чтобы это был циклический запрос? Можно так сделать? Типа: for(int i = 1; i <1000; i+=5) {}

Comment: циклов нет в `SQL`. Зато есть курсоры выборки и обычная переменная.

Comment: Спасибо, я реализовал что хотел этим способом: Update table set [bla-bla-bla] where (id % 5 = 0)

Comment: @Влад почему бы вам не ответить на вопрос в таком случае? Это бы помогло другим пользователям с таким вопросом и сделало бы сайт лучше.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update table set [bla-bla-bla] where (id % 5 = 0)
```